# How should a Lazy Optional quantifier behave?

Tags: regex, regex-greedy

I was reading about quantifiers and recognized the existence of the `??` (lazy optional) quantifier. I've been running some tests since then but the behaviour of this quantifier looks quite inconsistent.

Could any of you guys provide me with an example for this operator?

Also, I tried testing the regex `/a??b+/` for the string `abbb` which gave me the unexpected match of `abbb`. I was as expecting `bbb` as match since the lazy quantifier would prioritize the smaller match possible.

For the regex `/a+b??/` and the string `aaab`, the match is the expected `aaa` against the `aaab` matched by the greedy regex `/a+b?/`.

I appreciate in advance and hope you guys can help me understand what is happening here. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be better illustrated against `aa` with:

```
(a?)(a+)
```

https://regex101.com/r/c6tNrM/2

> Ensure that group 1 one has an `a`. Give the rest of the `a` chars to group 2

vs

```
(a??)(a+)
```

https://regex101.com/r/c6tNrM/3

> Group 1 might contain an `a` unless something else matches it more greedily in group 2

---

`/a+b??/` translates into:

- `a+` - give me all of the sequential `a` chars
- `b??` - give me one `b` char if it exists char but I prefer you don't unless there is more regex to be processed. Also, if `b` is matched in the additional regex then I don't want it.

`/a+b?/` translates to:

- `a+` - give me all of the sequential `a` chars
- `b?` - give me one `b` char if it exists

Comment: You are saying that a lazy optional quantifier gives up its match in favor of other greedier match. OK, that looks true for the example you've given. But that doesn't quite fit my problem where the second expression doesn't try to match the "a". If I'm missing something of you answer, could you please try to elucidate?

Comment: I got it! Summing this to what @Barmar said on his answer, if there is someting at the right side of the string being quantified, the quantifier will behave greedily unless what comes next would match the same thing by a "greedier" operator. Would you agree with that statement?

Comment: @JaimeMendes I think so, yes. I don't know if that is a thesis worthy explanation but it seems to describe the observed behavior.

Comment: @JaimeMendes Google RE2 provides a nice little "Repetitions" section at https://github.com/google/re2/wiki/Syntax which I think handily explains lazy and greedy quantifiers.

Answer (score 2):

Laziness only operates on the right, not the left. Searching for a pattern match operates from left to right. As soon as it finds a match for `a`, it will try to use it as long as the rest of the pattern matches. It doesn't matter whether `a?` is greedy or lazy.

Where the laziness matters is if you compare the patterns `a+b?` and `a+b??`, and have input like

```
aaab
```

The greedy version will match the whole string, the lazy version will match just `aaa`.